# How to connect interface array port to a concatenation of individual interfaces?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a module that has, as one of its ports, an unpacked array of an interface. I am trying to connect it to a few different singular interfaces using an assignment pattern, as I would for a simple port.

Doing so results in an error in QuestaSim:

> "Expected an interface instance as an actual for 'intf_out'."

What syntactic sugar do I need get this working?

I wrote a small example that shows the issue.

```
interface example_interface #(
   parameter SIZE = 4
);
   logic [SIZE-1:0] example_signal;
endinterface

module example_module (
   example_interface intf_in,
   example_interface intf_out [0:2]
);
   assign intf_out[0].example_signal = intf_in.example_signal;
   assign intf_out[1].example_signal = intf_in.example_signal;
   assign intf_out[2].example_signal = intf_in.example_signal;
endmodule

module example_port_connection ();
   example_interface #(.SIZE(3)) a ();
   example_interface #(.SIZE(4)) b ();
   example_interface #(.SIZE(5)) c ();
   example_interface #(.SIZE(6)) d ();

   example_module uut (
      .intf_in(a),
      .intf_out('{b,c,d}) //error here
   );
endmodule
```

Comment: The only way I could get this to work is using an interface array (ie `example_interface #(.SIZE(5)) b[0:2] ();` and hooking it up `.intf_out(b)`) but that isnt exactly what you want. The assignment statement (`'{...}`) doesnt seem to build interface arrays (which somewhat makes sense). this is just information and not an answer directly though; because Im not yet 100% convinced you cant build interface arrays from distinct instantiations yet. But if its possible in the language, it might not be possible in your tool.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in SystemVerilog using interfaces. Besides not having any syntax for a concatenation of interfaces, you no longer have an array when each element is a different type.

Comment: Would the elements really be different types though? I was under the impression that the reason you can't use non-constant indices to interface arrays (such as within a for loop inside an always block) was specifically because interface arrays *can* have different parameters for each element.

Comment: Yes. You can different parameterizations for different *instances*, but each instance becomes a different type. You become painfully aware of this when using `virtual interfaces`. An array is by definition a group of identically typed *things*

Comment: I've managed to get my example to compile and elaborate with an interface array using a `defparam` to assign a different `SIZE` for the instance at each index. I'm actually okay with using an array of interfaces instead of individually named ones, but they do require different parameterizations. Is there an ANSI style way to assign different parameters to each index?

Comment: You can only specify one set of parameter overrides with an array of instances. Forgot about `defparam` and suprized that it worked. But what is the use if `Intf_in.example_signal` is 4 bits and each `Intf_out.example_signal` is a different bit width?

Comment: Default mismatched assignment behaviour (truncation/0-extension) is acceptable for my actual use case.

Comment: Unfortunately `defparam` can't refer to outside scope from within a generate block, so I cannot use this method to define parameters for each index of an interface array where the size of the array is itself parameterized. Section C.4.1 of the spec also claims "The defparam statement does not provide a capability that cannot be done by another method that avoids these problems." as justification for possible future deprecation which seems inaccurate in this case.

Comment: I think that there is a hole in standard around this use of defparms. Even if it worked, which i doubt, it wold violate a notion of a regular (array) type. It cannot consists of elements of a different type (or array size), unlike java. So, i would not exploit this hole. You'd be better to rethink your algorithm.